# Json Schema: either declaring an array of one type OR another

Tags: jsonschema

How can I declare a property which could be an array of one type, i.e. string, or another, i.e. integer? I googled around and all I could find was a way of declaring array of mixed types.
I tried the following schema definition:

```
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-04/schema#",
  "definitions": {
    "content": {
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "string"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type": "array",
          "items": [
            {
              "type": "integer"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "content": {
      "$ref": "#/definitions/content"
    }
  }
}
```

which validates

```
{
  "content": [
     1, 2
  ]  
}
```

and

```
{
  "content": [
     "a", "b"
  ]  
}
```

but also validates

```
{
  "content": [
     1, "a"
  ]  
}
```

that I should consider invalid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're using the wrong variation of the `items` keyword.  There is one form that takes a schema and another variation that takes an array of schemas.

The schema variation means all elements must match the schema.  The following schema defines an array where all values are strings.

```
{
  "items": { "type": "string" }
}
```

The array of schemas variation describes a tuple.  The first schema validates the first item, the second schema validates the second item, and so on.  The following schema validates an array where the first item is an integer, the second is string, and the third is a boolean.

```
{
  "items": [
    { "type": "integer" },
    { "type": "string" },
    { "type": "boolean" }
  ]
}
```

It's very rare to need the tuple variation of `items`.  You almost always want the the other one.

Comment: This may be the accepted answer but it doesn't actually address the OP's question.  They are *not* using the wrong form of the `items` keyword; their approach is the recommended one to accept an array where all items are of the same type, and that type is one of two possible types.

Comment: @EdGraham They are using the wrong form of `items`, but you are correct that the answer doesn't directly answer the question. Instead it corrects the error and allows the OP to figure out the rest himself. See https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html#items for more information.

Comment: You are quite right: I didn't spot that the OP had specified an array with one item in it!  So the correct form would be as they had it but without the `[]` characters.  Thanks for clarifying!

Answer (score 1):

Your schema appears in order. I'm inclined to think this would be a bug in the implementation you're using it to validate the `[1, "a"]` variant. Have you tested this with different implementations or considered filing a bug with the implementation you did try here?

Comment: I've been trying a couple of online validators, such as http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ and https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/ but they both validate the `[1, "a"]` case, that's why I didn't think about a validation software bug

Comment: It seems those use [Newtonsoft.Json.Schema](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json.Schema) and [json-schema-validator](https://github.com/java-json-tools/json-schema-validator). Perhaps you could file this there to get their view on why `[1, "a"]` would pass validation here.

Comment: I agree with @KiaraGrouwstra - the schema seems valid.  I wonder whether replacing `oneOf` with `anyOf` would have made a difference?

Comment: ... actually, now I agree with Jason above: I didn't spot that the OP had specified `items` as *an array* with a single element in it.  If you take the array away, it should work.